# JMustache attribution is incorrectly listed as Butterknife

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Butterknife appears twice in the OSS attribution list of the Android app (v1.0.85). Based on the links, the second one should be JMustache.

[image]

Comment: Noticed this as well, and they still haven't changed it. They need someone to maintain their app, even if they can't add new features

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been (finally) fixed as of today, June 30th, 2017 with version 1.0.95 of the Android app.

From [Kasra Rahjerdi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/472021/kasra-rahjerdi) on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/350386/2415822):

> Thanks for catching this! Copy pasting so many times led me to totally looking past it.
>
> This is fixed as of version 1.0.2, live now. It'll also be fixed in the Stack Exchange app as of the next update (1.0.95), which isn't live yet.

Comment: So sad such a trivial bug sat idle here for over a year, Kasra never bothered to look in MSE to see bugs. And he still doesn't, only in MSO for the shiny new app. Guess some things never change.